# Aggregating and calculating weekly differences in CSV reports with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Overflow Data/CSV/Pandas peeps hivemind....I need your help!

I've only recently started using Python/Pandas and I found a really good project to possibly work on, that would save me a lot of time.

I do weekly reports and report on the differences in data week by week.

I dont know Pandas 100% but I dont think this would be that hard to do with code and I feel like this project would be a great way for me to learn.

Here is an example of the report I have:
[Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeOe5.png)

Now, I have a list of items from the items list (and gets concatenated in the item info column) that I'm to be reporting on:

I'm essentially trying to have code that can compute:

-**IF** the name (from my list) is found in the item info column AND the Week number(s) is a particular number AND the year(s) is 2022 THEN aggregate the total number of the POS/sales altogether as data A

**&**

-**IF** there is viable data there as well for Week 16 (compute the similar above info for that week as data B), then subtract the difference between these weeks (A and B) and output that data to me as information point C (aka the difference)

-**THEN** if that difference is positive, divide C by B (aka, give me the percentage of that move)

Tl:dr-I want to aggregate the total sales of an item for the week and subtract it from the corresponding amount for the previous week for the same item and verify the difference, as well as the percentage of movement in amounts.

I only know so much in Pandas right now, would anyone be able to point me in a direction that could help? I so feel like this shouldn't be that hard to do/I'd love to make it a weekend project and saves myself a good bit of time at work and learn how to automate some work tasks too. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What *specific* issues have you run into? What have your produced on your own? SO is great at answering specific questions, but we're not here to write your code for you~ [Pandas Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp)

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391).